# Maximum and Minimum value of function -8x^2 -3 at interval (-inf, +inf)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limsup-and-liminf, maxima-minima

**Updates:** Correcting a mistake, adding MathJax and removing screenshot...

I'm trying to find maximum & minimum value of function -8x^2-3 at an interval (-inf, +inf), which is an open interval by nature. 
Taking limits at -inf and +inf results in -inf, i.e. this function has a Maximum or maximum value, but no minimum value.
Finding critical points gives x=0
Evaluating function at x=16 gives -3.
Although, this is the only value, but -ve sign shows, it should be a Minima, not Maxima.
Here is my effort.

**Taking Limits:**
$$\lim{x\to -\infty}=-\infty $$
$$\lim{x\to +\infty}=-\infty
$$

Shows that it has a maximum, but no minimum value;

**Finding Critical Point:**
$$ \bar f(x)=-16x $$
**Equating to 0:**
$$ -16x=0 => x=0 $$
**Evaluating function at x=0:**
$$ f(0)=-3 $$

As this contains -ve sign, I think, it is the minimum value. So what I am missing or confusing here?

Comment: -16x=0 => x=0  , f(0) is a maximal value.

Comment: Please format your question appropriately and use inline markup rather than attaching a screenshot.

Comment: @edcharlie: Thanks a lot for catching my mistake... But still f(0)=-3 so isn't it a minimal value?

Comment: @anomaly, sure, I will use MathJx next time.

Comment: Why should a negative value mean a minimum?  Can't a function contain only negative values and have a negative as it's maximum?  And you *JUST SAID* (and a I quote) "Shows that it has a maximum, but no minimum value".  So if has a maximum and no minimum how can this be a minimum value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$-8x^2-3\leq-3.$$
The equality occurs for $x=0$, which says that $-3$ is a maximal value.

The minimal value does not exist.

Comment: Ahh, my mistake for wrongly evaluating -16x=0... Thanks for update..

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

> Shows that it has a maximum, but no minimum value;

Yes, yes, it does.  Put a pin in that:  It has a maximum.  It has no minimum.

> As this contains -ve sign, I think, it is the minimum value.

Well, okay but let's go back to the pin.  "It has a maximum.  It has no minimum."

So that can't be right.

> So what I am missing or confusing here?

Well, *Why* do think it is a minimum value?  You say that because $f(0) = -3$ and $-3$ has a negative sign it must be a minimum.

Okay, *why* do you think that?

If something is negative, it *must* be a minimum?  It can't be a maximum?

Really?

Can't a negative number ever be a *maximum*?  Can't a function always be negative? After all a if a minimum can be *positive* for a function that is always positive (such as $g(x) = 8x^2 + 3\ge 3$), couldn't a function that is always negative  (such as $f(x) = -8x^2 - 3 \le -3$) have a maximum that is negative?

After all.  $x^2 \ge 0$ so $-x^2 \le 0$ so $-8x^2 \le 0$ and $-8x^2 -3 \le -3$.  So $-8x^2 - 3$ is always less than $0$ so is there any reason it *shouldn't* have a maximum that is less than $0$?

So...  You did all the work.  And you did it all correctly.

$-8x^2 - 3$ has a *maximum* when $x = 0$ and that maximum is $-8*0^2 - 3 = -3$.  And, yes, that maximum *is* negative.  Which is *not* a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks bro.. Yes, I got that point... -1 is greater than -2 :)